# XSL printing child nodes

Tags: xslt, nodes, children

I have an xml file that has an `address` node that looks like

```
<address>
   <city>Anywhere</city>
   <state>NJ</city>
   <zip>12345</zip>
</address>
```

Right now, in the resulting xml file it prints out as

```
 Anywhere
 NJ
 12345
```

I'm trying to write a block in my xsl transform file to transform it to print as

```
 Anywhere, NJ 12345
```

But I'm not sure how to go about selecting the individual child nodes

I want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="address">
    <city>, <state> <zip>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/> <xsl:value-of select="zip"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks I had a slight error in my syntax before. Now this is working.